# Android test bitmap and input stream: Unit or how?

Tags: android, unit-testing, bitmap, android-espresso, android-testing

I have a class with a method

```
private Bitmap getBitmap(@NonNull final Context context, final Uri screenshotUri) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    if (screenshotUri != null) {
        try {
            final InputStream input = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(screenshotUri);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, new BitmapFactory.Options());
            if (input != null) {
                input.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Not important
        }
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

Now I'm at the point where I need to test it but I am not sure how should I approach it best

Should the test be a unitTest and go in the `test` folder, mocking all kind of `Context`, `ContentResolver`, BitmapFactory class (static so probably I will need an injection in the function)?

Or should this test be put in the `androidTest` folder where I could use the `InstrumentationRegistry.getContext()`? 
But then I guess I should also write temporarily in memory the bitmap that should then be read.

I only have Mockito and Espresso libraries and cannot add neither Powermockito nor Robolectric.

Comment: You should not test framework classes, you should suppose that those are already tested by the android team

Comment: Thank you, but here I would like to test this function (not the framework ones), specifically testing that if I give in input an `Uri` of an existing image it's going to return it, and if I put an `Uri` of a non existing image it's gonna return `null`

Comment: This is a great question I am also facing it right now! @JuanCruzSoler's comment helped me a lot, thanks! I have a Bitmap transformation utility class too, from where I called Bitmap.crop or rotate methods, I intended to test if these functions work well, e.g.: whether the bitmap will be rotated as expected, but obviously if we treat these functions as unit test cases, we won't see the bitmaps at all! Therefore I agree with Juan, we should suppose they are well tested - by Android team!